# have more control by having my own template using angular ui

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pysqmDkRbAt3cQhgGJ3h?p=preview) link

I added ng-show / ng-click etc event with cross js file (btw line 3404 angular ui js and line 16 my own js file) and it doesn't work.

how to create my own template so that I can have more control?

Comment: I've got no idea what this is asking? do you want to use a different template for each tab in the list of tabs?

Comment: @BenCr there are generated template in angular ui js, but I add ng-show there, is just isn't working and modifying the library is a bad practice.

Comment: find out why my ng-show isn't work then you'll know my problem.

Comment: The ng-show does work, you're just binding it to a property which is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Your ng-show is working exactly as it should, the expression you're using in your ng-show refers to a property which doesn't exist on the scope and is therefore evaluating as false.

Add the following to your TabsParentController and you'll see your buttons.

```
$scope.showDeleteButton = true;
```

Here's a link to a working plunkr.

http://plnkr.co/edit/jxsnwyiwBeJQXiORbu8N?p=preview

Comment: Any comment about the reason for downvoting?

Comment: you did not answer my question properly, btw I'm not the one who downvoted it. I bind the showdeletebtn in the angularui js, not my own js file. check out line 3404

Comment: Okay, I've updated my plunkr so it answers your question. I'll update the answer here now.

Comment: Oh, actually I've just updated it to do exactly what the other answer said, sorry.

Comment: although it still doesn't solve my problem, I gave u an upvote :) because only the mouse hover over the text the button show up, imagine the width of the <li> is longer than the item name's length, that would produce not very decent UX. The user might hardly notice the existence of the delete button.

Comment: Yes well in my opinion adding the delete button on hover isn't great ux, the user might never know the existence of a delete button if they only see the default tab and never hover over the actual tab header. It'd be much better to just show the delete button permanently on the active tab and hide it on the inactive tabs. Then there will never be doubt that the user has seen the button and your problem is solved and you can go on to implement actual functionality rather than this  superfluous flourish.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `ng-mouseleave` and `ng-mouseover` directives to `<tab-heading>` element and remove them from library code.

http://plnkr.co/edit/2kmNEKp2li6hyCBOg9yP?p=preview

Comment: this work and I also tried it. But the problem is I still don't have enough control over it. Because I bind to the li, you can see the delete button showing up when u hover on the text.